# Stopping an "await" in a function, from another function (Discord.py)

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

So I am new to programming. I decide to take on a project to help me learn how to code. I am currently working on a discord bot using discord.py to create a game similar to the mobile game "BitLife". However, I am running into an issue where I run a command to restart my life and then start a new one directly afterwards and each message is repeated twice.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = discord.Client()

TOKEN = 'bot_token'
yesno = ['✅', '❌']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if (message.content.lower() == 'lb! startlife') or (message.content.lower() == 'lb! sl'):
        if life == 0 or life == None:
            life = 1

            #Variables get set up here, such as age

            age = 0

            await gameRun(message, life)
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Hold On!', description='You already have a life started! Please use "LB! ContinueLife" to continue you life, or "LB! Reset" to restart your life.', color=0x0000ff)
            await message.reply(embed=embed)
    elif (message.content.lower() == 'lb! endlife') or (message.content.lower() == 'lb! el'):
        if life == 1:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Are You Sure?', description='You are about to commit suicide and end your life. This CANNOT be reversed. \n\nTo confirm your death, please react with :white_check_mark: below, to cancel, please react with :x: \n\nAction will be canceled automatically after 1 minute!', color=0x0000ff)
            botmsg = await message.reply(embed=embed)
            for emoji in yesno:
                await botmsg.add_reaction(emoji)

            def check(reaction, user):
                return user == message.author and (str(reaction.emoji) == '✅' or str(reaction.emoji) == '❌')

            try:  
                reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError: 
                await message.reply('Action canceled ❌')
            else:    
                if reaction.emoji == '✅':
                    life = 0
                    commandLoop = 0
                    
                    #Death message

                elif reaction.emoji == '❌':
                    await message.reply('Action canceled ❌')      
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Hold On!', description='You have no life to end! Begin your life by doing "LB! StartLife"', color=0x0000ff)
            await message.reply(embed=embed)
    elif (message.content.lower() == 'lb! continuelife') or (message.content.lower() == 'lb! cl'):
        if life == 1:
            if commandLoop == 0:
                await gameRun(message, life)
            else:
                embed=discord.Embed(title='Hold On!', description='You already have a game active. Please wait for the game to timeout to use this command', color=0x0000ff)
                await message.reply(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title='Hold On!', description='You have no life to continue! Please use "LB! StartLife" to start your life.', color=0x0000ff)
            await message.reply(embed=embed)

async def gameRun(message, life):

    commandLoop = 1
    while (life == 1) and (commandLoop == 1):

        if (age == 0) and (age < 1):
            
            #Embed is set up here for users to view their stats

            botmsg = await message.reply(embed=embed)
            
            await botmsg.add_reaction('')

            def check(reaction, user):
                return user == message.author and (str(reaction.emoji) == '')

            try:  
                reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                commandLoop = 0
                await message.reply('Action timed out, please use "LB! ContinueLife" to continue')
            else:     
                elif reaction.emoji == '':
                    age = age + 1
        
        elif (age[id] >= 1) and (age[id] < 4):
            #Same proccess is repeated just with more options
        elif (age[id] >= 4) and (age[id] < 16):
            #Same proccess is repeated just with more options
        elif (age[id] >= 16) and (age[id] < 18):
           #Same proccess is repeated just with more options
        else:
            #Same proccess is repeated just with more options
```

I'm almost certain that the reason the messages are repeating is due to the code still waiting for the user to react from the await in "reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120.0, check=check)". I need the await in order for the bot to work correctly. I need to know how to get around the await when I use the "LB! EndLife" command.

Here are some pictures that show what happens:

[Image 1: First LB! StartLife command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vES5.png)
Works fine. Click the reaction, age up, and view the next year's info

[Image 2: LB! EndLife command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtDBs.png)
Ends the life fine as it should

[Image 3: Using the LB! StartLife again right after ending the previous life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7tk2.png)
This is when the bug happens. As shown, when the user reacts, the responding bot message is repeated

[Image 4: Reverts back after a timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHMof.png)
Everything works fine after the timeout. This is what's letting me know that is the "await" that is causing this

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the commands extension, so you can actually write commands, instead of doing everything in an on_message event.
To use that, you'll need `commands.Bot` instead of `discord.Client`

Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/dank-tagg/42349435b675573094c5891ce7605f0f

That is so much easier, right?
If you run into any problems, just comment beneath the gist.